# Google Firebase / BigQuery - no previous data available

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

Recently we have linked our Firebase project with BigQuery.

But there are no previous (before linking) events data displayed in BigQuery console. Is there a way to get previous data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Analytics events will be inserted into BigQuery from the moment you connect the two. There is no way to get the events from before you connected them.