# Normal for BigQuery data to be higher than Firebase?

Tags: sql, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-bigquery

I'm running the following query to select the active users for a time frame on my project.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  active_users,
  unix
FROM [mobileapp_logs].[dbo].[active_users]
WHERE (rtrim(app_id) + ':' + app_os) = 'tbl'
AND [aggregation] = '30-day-active'
AND [unix] BETWEEN 1491696000 AND 1494288000
AND active_users >= 100
```

The query seems to be working but with every row returned for that day it will give me about 10 - 30 more than what's in firebase. Is this normal for bigquery -> firebase?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the table you are querying, according to the documentation Firebase imports data to `app_events_intraday_YYYYMMDD`. Could you provide more information about [mobileapp_logs].[dbo].[active_users]?

According to [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853347/discrepancies-on-active-users-metric-between-firebase-analytics-dashboard-and) SO [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41593354/extracting-firebase-bigquery-daus-waus-and-maus) it seems there may be a delay of a few days where offline devices upload their data. Also Firebase updates data in BigQuery daily. Since you are querying up until today you may be seeing data that has already been updated in Firebase but not in BigQuery. I would recommend changing your query to a range ending 3 days before today.